# Glitches while playing audio in Android

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

I am using **MediaPlayer** to play audio in Android. `MediaPlayer` is working perfectly but when I use a **SeekBar** which is updated with the duration of audio, the audio doesn't play smoothly and breaks while playing. Below is my code snippet for reference.

```
mSongSeekBar.setMax(mMediaPlayer.getDuration());
    mSongSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            mMediaPlayer.seekTo(progress);
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }
    });

    new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mSongSeekBar.setProgress(mMediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition());
        }
    }, 0, 500);
```

What is the reason for this behavior? How to get rid of this? Should I go with any alternative of **Timer**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem where the audio was continuously seeking by itself and causing glitches. You need to make sure the audio is seeked only when the user scrubs it and not when it is normally running. For this purpose the boolean fromUser parameter of onProgressChanged is useful. This would ensure the audio seeking only when the user scrubs it.

```
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
      if(fromUser){
        mMediaPlayer.seekTo(progress);
       }
    }
```

Comment: This one worked for me! I am now able to understand the actual reason behind breaking audio :)

Answer (score 1):

**Reason**

Audio is not playing continuously, it is changing every 500 millisecond, and so it feels breaking. Because ***Timer()*** is changing the value of ***Progress*** integer. And *mMediaPlayer* seeks to it every time automatically, as the code is written:

```
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
        mMediaPlayer.seekTo(progress);
    }
```

**How to Get rid of this**

You should use boolean fromUser to change position of audio, only when user changes seekBar manually, You can do this by just a little change(using if)

```
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
    if (fromUser)
    mMediaPlayer.seekTo(progress);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You might consider overriding the `onStartTrackingTouch` and `onStopTrackingTouch` methods as well. Because when you are dragging the seek-bar the `onProgressChanged` is called frequently and each time it is trying to set the media player to play from a specific position and hence you are getting that cracking or breaking of your audio.

I would recommend, pausing the media player temporarily while the seek-bar being dragged and resume the audio when you are done with the dragging. The methods mentioned above might help you to achieve those behaviors.

Comment: But the problem is there even when I am not scrolling the **SeekBar**! The normal playback of audio is breaking. When I comment out the **Timer** implementation, it works perfectly! So, there is some problem with the usage of **Timer** for realtime update of duration of the audio.

Comment: I see. Actually, it's breaking due to the similar reason that I stated I think. Why do you need the timer though?

Comment: I am using Timer to update SeekBar with current duration of audio. As you can see, Timer is updating SeekBar after every 0.5 seconds.

Comment: I am getting what you stated. But that will be the case only when I am dragging the SeekBar. In my case, I am not dragging the SeekBar still the audio is breaking!